# New to MongoDB: Can't get into mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I've just installed MongoDB via Homebrew, and I'm trying to get it up and running. I've launched it using `mongod`in the command line, and now I'm trying to get into the shell by using the command `mongo` once it is running. However, nothing happens when I run the command. Here is a paste of my log:

```
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17731 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=lsadmin’s-MacBook-Pro
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] 
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimountain.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/    RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true",     logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.458 [initandlisten] journal dir=/usr/local/var/mongodb/journal
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.459 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.543 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Sep  6 16:54:02.543 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Sep  6 16:55:02.552 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 14ms
```

And this is a paste of my config file:

```
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

And a paste of command line:

```
-> mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a second shell and then running `./mongo` in `/usr/local/cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/` allowed me access to the shell.

Obvious solution, but documentation makes it seem like you can run it from the mongod prompt.

Comment: There is no mongod prompt. `mongod` is the server. I believe what happened is that you tried typing into the shell where mongod was started as a foreground task. If you had run `./mongod &`, then the server would have started in the background and you would have gotten your command prompt back. You do not need to open a second command shell to run the `mongo` shell.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Perhaps they've updated things, but a "mongod" command does exist. I'm not quite clear what you meant by "There is no mongod prompt", but I take it you were referring to prompt as command.

I do like the idea of using "./mongod &" though, but perhaps leaving it open is useful for debugging/learning.

If you use "mongod", you will need a second shell though. So Neil is right about that.

Comment: @Joe - you didn't understand what I wrote (nor Neil, as he called out a nonexistent "mongod prompt"). I never said the `mongod` command does not exist. `mongod` (which is actually an app, not a command, but that's getting pedantic) is the server, and yes, it's run from your machine's command prompt. But that is not a mongodb prompt. You cannot enter commands into it. If you want a mongodb prompt, you need to run the `mongo` shell (and the shell will connect to the server being hosted by the `mongod` process). Exactly as I said a year ago. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Fair enough on the technicalities. However, Neil did mention the "mongo" command as well, but that wasn't the issue I was trying to point out.